# Search array for sting and echo the value of the matched key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$europe =  array("Albania" => "AL","Andorra" => "AD","Austria" => "AT","Belarus" => "BY","Belgium" => "BE","Bosnia and Herzegovina" => "BA","Bulgaria" => "BG","Croatia" => "HR","Cyprus" => "CY",
"Czech Republic" => "CZ","Denmark" => "DK","Estonia" => "EE","Faroe Islands" => "FO","Finland" => "FI","France" => "FR","Germany" => "DE","Gibraltar" => "GI","Greece" => "GR","Hungary" => "HU","Iceland" => "IS","Ireland" => "IE","Italy" => "IT","Latvia" => "LV","Liechtenstein" => "LI","Lithuania" => "LT","Luxembourg" => "LU","Macedonia" => "MK","Malta" => "MT","Moldova" => "MD","Monaco" => "MC","Netherlands" => "NL","Norway" => "NO","Poland" => "PL","Portugal" => "PT","Romania" => "RO","Russia" => "RU","San Marino" => "SM","Serbia" => "RS","Slovakia" => "SK","Slovenia" => "SI","Spain" => "ES","Sweden" => "SE","Switzerland" => "CH","Ukraine" => "UA","United Kingdom" => "GB","Vatican city" => "VA","Yugoslavia" => "RS","Isle of Man" => "IM","Kosovo" => "RS","Montenegro" => "ME");
```

I wish to search the array for a string match of the country and retrieve the country code

```
$search = $_GET["site_search"];
foreach ($europe as $country => $cc){
if (strtolower($country) == $search){
echo $cc;
}
}
```

But I don't think the above is efficient as it loops and checks  each key.

So I thought about using array_search..

```
echo array_search($search,$europe,true);
```

but the above echos put the country (key) not the country code (value)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using it as the key if the cases are the same:

```
echo $europe[$_GET["site_search"]];
```

Or normalize the case to match the keys:

```
$key = ucfirst(strtolower($_GET["site_search"]));
echo $europe[$key];
```